# tensorflow @python3.10 tried many times but no improvement

Tags: tensorflow

i have installed 3.10 version of python and now facing problem to inastall tensorflow C:\Python\python310>pip install tensorflow ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Comment: Tensorflow supports upto `Python 3.9` only. You can [refer here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Tf-nightly Python3.10 wheels supports Linux and MacOS. You can get them via pip install tf-nightly on the corresponding operating system.

Take a look at this [#comment](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/support-python-3-10/124/15?u=ashwini_gadag)